# MySQL .Net connection pool connection.Open() very slow

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

Version 6.4.4:

Using the most basic implementation of MySqlConnection, the following code takes 2-5 seconds per connection when preloading the connection pool to reach the "Min Pool Size" configured in my connection string.

Any ideas why it is taking so long, how to fix, or workarounds?

Connection String:

```
<add name="users" connectionString="server=192.168.1.2;User Id=dbuser;password=dbpassword;database=users;Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=10;Max Pool Size=50;Persist Security Info=True;" />
```

Code

```
private static void MySqlConnectionTester()
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["users"].ConnectionString;

    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "select * from users;";

            try
            {
                connection.Open(); // This line hangs until "Min Pool Size" is reached.
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                        // Read results
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // Log exception
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At [MySQL's homepage](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html) they write that you should avoid creating, opening and closing the connection object youself, instead you should use the helper class which should work better with connectionpooling.

I have not tested it, but was something I just read :)

Comment: I know of the information your talking about. Their suggestion is to not create your own MySqlConnection() object, but instead use the MySqlConnection(connectionString) overload. Pooling is managed by distinct connectionstring.

Comment: @TexasViking Have you considered that it is the server/network that is the bootleneck and not the Connector?

Comment: I have considered it. I was planning on getting mysql installed locally today to test that theory. However, when I remove the "custom" connection string pooling settings, I am able to create connections almost instantly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was also present on our side with MySql Connector .Net 6.6.5. The MySql Connector .Net 6.8.3 is solving this issue.

Fabrice